# Upgrade Eclipse Helios to Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm attempting to upgrade my eclipse helios (3.6.1) to indigo (3.7.2). I found this page [(From Helios to Indigo is easy)](http://prapicault.blogspot.com//2011/06/from-helios-to-indigo-is-easy.html) which identifies 2 ways that (may) expedite the process. I started with the first method (add the indigo repository and use Help->Check for Updates) but I ran into a lot of dependency issues. After doing some research I found that most people recommended starting with a fresh indigo instance. So then I moved on to method #2. But the issue I'm having now is that I can't import the plugins using the method described. When I specify the path to the previous application installation, the import wizard tells me that it isn't a valid location.

[image]

Any feedback I can get on successful methods that people used to upgrade their eclipse instance would be much appreciated. The OS is CentOS 5.5 btw.

Update: 
After initially posting the question I thought this might be a permissions issue so I went back and ran eclipse 3.7.2 as root. Then it the import wizard did accept the previous eclipse instance as valid, but it only gives me the eclipse SDK as an option to import which doesn't seem right.

[image]

Comment: I just create a new install, and re-install the plugins from their home repository.  Old plugins for a previous version may not work for the new version, though most will.  Google the plugin you want, and it'll tell you how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to do the update from the Indigo repository after removing the one or two plugins that were causing dependency issues.

I then re-installed the problematic plugins with their latest versions after the update. Worked fine.